# Foreign keys with Sequelize are not created

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize for my Server (with mysql dialect); in Sequelize's documentation is written that this:

```
var Task = this.sequelize.define('Task', { title: Sequelize.STRING })
, User = this.sequelize.define('User', { username: Sequelize.STRING })

User.hasMany(Task)
Task.belongsTo(User)
```

creates automatically foreign key references with constraints;
but for me this doesn't happen:

```
var Shop = sequelize.define('Shop', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    address: Sequelize.STRING,
    phone: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    percentage: Sequelize.FLOAT,
    text: Sequelize.TEXT,
    categories: Sequelize.TEXT,
    start: Sequelize.DATE,
    end: Sequelize.DATE
});

var Offer = sequelize.define('Offer', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    deadline: Sequelize.DATE,
    optionDuration: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

Shop.hasMany(Offer);
Offer.belongsTo(Shop);
```

This creates the two tables shops and offers, both of them with only "id" primary key

I also have some n:m associations like:

```
Group.hasMany(Accesslevel);
Accesslevel.hasMany(Group);
```

but also in this case, in the join table that Sequelize creates, there are no foreign key;
so if I delete for ex. an acccesslevel, than the corresponding records in the join table accesslevelsgroups are not deleted.

Does anybody know if I'm doing something wrong or missing something?
What I need is to create all the foreign keys for the associations and the possibility to specify the behaviour 'onDelete' and 'onUpdate' (cascade)

-- UPDATE
I've created a route for executing sync:

```
myServer.get('/sync', function (req, res) {
    sequelize.sync({force: true}).success(function() {
        console.log('sync done');
        res.send(200, 'sync done');
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log('there was a problem');
        res.send(200, 'there was a problem');
    });
});
```

So then in the browser I type 127.0.0.1:port/sync to create the db structure

Comment: sequelize doesnt support foreign keys.You need to create them yourself.

Comment: @mpm That is blatelnly incorrect, http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/associations#foreign-keys

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer well that was the case when I used it,glad it is now supported.

Comment: Yes, I was just linking the same doc page... But do you know why in my case the foreign keys are not created automatically as the doc says?

Comment: did you add the relation after creating the table ? did you call `sync`, you need `force: true` to update tables ( will drop the table ). Are you using InnoDB ?

Comment: You mean after the sync()?

Comment: I think problem is with versions. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394449/sequelize-not-creating-foreign-key/48346624#48346624

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you add the relation after creating the table ( in the database ) ?
You need `.sync({ force: true })` if you modify your scheme's and run your program again. 
Sequelize will only create the table and all it's references if the table does not exist yet in the database.

Are you calling sync after all associations have been made ?

Are you using InnoDB ?

Oddly enough I can reproduce that, The easiest fix is to define the key manually I think, that's how I solved it, Might be a bug otherwise I'm not sure.

See here:
http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/associations#block-3-line-24

Comment: I define all associations right after the models, as wrote in the first post; then I've created a route /sync in the server that executed the sync({force: true}), and another route /dummy-data that inserts automatically some records; so I run /sync and then /dummy-data... I use InnoDB...

Comment: @CerealKiller What version are you using, seems like this might be an issue in `< 1.7.6` https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/1818

Comment: I'm using the latest Sequelize 2.0.0-dev9 - Thank you for this, I'll follow the issue too

Comment: Ok in the end the problem is due to an issue regarding n:m association; in other cases (1:n) works

Answer (score 1):

You should give foreign keys like that, it is not related to sync.

```
Offer.associate = function (models) {
    models. Offer.belongsTo(models. Offer, {
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        foreignKey: 'shopId',
        targetKey: 'id'
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was actually answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26426530/4728612)

As trivial answers are converted to comments and it is hard to notice them under question I'll duplicate its main point here.

> > To add references constraints to the columns, you can pass the options onUpdate and onDelete to the association calls. . . .
>
> User.hasMany(Task, { onDelete: 'SET NULL', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })