# Sequelize doesn't create a foreign key column on a populated table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

This is my popular example database :
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx/

I need to create a customer_id foreign key in the payments table, using squelize :

```
  payments.belongsTo(customers, {
        foreignKey: 'customer_id',
    });
```

Unfortunatly, The foreignKey column is not automatically created by sequelize while it should, however, if I use this command :

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true })
```

The column is created, but my full database is content cleared !

1. What is the solution to keep my actual data ?
2. Do I have to create manually each foreign columns ?
3. If yes, what is the exact syntax ?

Thanks a lot !

P.S : The tables are populated with examples datas. I  don't want to clear this data .
P.S : I use https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto to generate data models from the existing database .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreign keys with Sequelize are not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309893/foreign-keys-with-sequelize-are-not-created)

Comment: No, I need to know if Sequelize can create foreign keys on populated tables or not, thank you I have seen this post before.

Comment: I need to be sure 100% if Sequelize can create foreign keys on populated tables or not

Comment: I am not familiar with Sequelize.JS. Hope that you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `foreignKey` in your model payments with other columns like below you can see this example in git readme of repository link you have given

**Example** = https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto#typescript

```
payments.belongsTo(customers, {
  foreignKey: 'customer_id',
  targetKey: 'id'
});

customer_id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER(),
    allowNull: false,
      references: {
    model: 'customers',
      key: 'id'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try out this tonight, Please notice, I have changed a few my initial message for more simplicity ( customerNumber_id becomes customer_id)